# Maple Lie Derivative - Cannot enter vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, maple, lie-derivative

Can someone please offer some suggestion for dealing with this error? I am going nuts with this. I followed the Maple documentation in entering this and apparently Maple doesn't think the vector field I entered is in fact a vector field.

My Code:

with(DifferentialGeometry); with(LieAlgebras);

DGSetup([x, y, z], M);

X := evalDG(-D_z*x^2+D_x*y+D_y*z);

```
              X := -D_z x  + D_x y + D_y z
```

alpha := evalDG(x*`&w`(dy, dz));

```
                    alpha := x dy dz
```

LieDerivative(X, alpha);

Error, (in DifferentialGeometry:-LieDerivative) expected 1st argument to be a vector field. Received -D_z*x^2+D_x*y+D_y*z

Comment: Try here: https://www.mapleprimes.com

Answer (score 2):

You used DGSetup, where you should use DGsetup (lower-case "s"). You omitted an asterisk (*) for scalar multiplication in the first two terms of your vector field.

Comment: Thank you so much cgtorre! I had fixed the asterisk issue afterward but never came close to noticing the error with DGsetup. It works!